# Grub Error 18 - Solid State Drive

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, grub

I recently used Raw Copy to make an image of my 300gb Raptor Hd to a OCZ Vertex SSD 60GB. And When I pluged in the SSD to boot I get a Grub Error 18. I have tried to changed in the BIOS setting to LBA, Large, Auto, trying different combination's.

Any advice.

thanks,
Clint

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest fix is to boot from a linux live cd and use grub to fix the error. [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=224351) link should help you get everything up and running again